# GWT issues when using RPC

Tags: gwt

I have spend more than one day trying to create a very simple hello world application in GWT but I am not being successful. I am trying to get a hello string from the server through RPC and display it on the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download a fresh copy of [Eclipse Helios for java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1)
- Install the appropriate [GWT Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.html)
- Start Eclipse, go to File->New Project, search for Google/Web Application Project
- Project properties, Run As... Web Application

At this point you should have a fully functional GWT application.

Comment: I'd just add, "Project properties, Run As... Web Application". Then open the URL displayed and you're running the application in Development Mode (provided you install the developer plugin as prompted) and can start to tinker with the code. Clicking on the red GWT toolbox icon will bring up a GWT compile, and this will produce pure Javascript version that will run in ANY web browser (w/Javascript obviously).